# Can Gentzen-style proofs give omega-consistency and beyond?

Tags: lo.logic, ordinal-numbers, ordinal-analysis

In 1936, Gentzen famously showed that Primitive Recursive Arithmetic, plus the assumption that the ordinal $\epsilon_0$ is well-founded, is able to prove Con(PA).  But of course, Con(PA) doesn't yet imply PA is *sound*, so we might wonder how far a Gentzen-style proof can go toward establishing soundness.

At this point, you might interject that soundness isn't even first-order definable, so *of course* we can't hope for a formal proof that PA is sound.  But it seems to me that we can mostly sidestep that problem using Tarski's prescription, which lets us formally define soundness *for whatever fixed number of quantifiers we care about* (that is, for $\Sigma_k$ and $\Pi_k$ sentences for any fixed $k$).  So in particular, given any fixed arithmetical sentence---let's say $P\ne NP$, which is a $\Pi_2$-sentence---it seems reasonable to hope for a proof of the following implication, within Primitive Recursive Arithmetic:

  If $\epsilon_0$ is well-founded and PA proves $P\ne NP$, then $P\ne NP$ holds.

My question is, **does the technology of ordinal proof theory (about which I know almost nothing) let us establish statements like the above?**  Also, if we want to establish such a thing for a $\Pi_k$-sentence, does the ordinal that we need increase with $k$, or does the same ordinal (e.g., $\epsilon_0$) always suffice?

(This question is a followup to my recent question about [an ordinal encoding the proof strength of ZF](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164148/is-there-a-computable-ordinal-encoding-the-proof-strength-of-zf-is-it-knowable), and arose from discussion with Timothy Chow there.)

Comment: Yes. And what increases with $k$ is not the ordinal ($\epsilon_0$), but the complexity of the formula on which you apply transfinite induction (it will be $\Pi_{k-2}$ or something). Primitive recursive transfinite induction should suffice for $\Pi_2$-soundness.

Comment: Thanks, Emil!!  So then, is it known just how far primitive recursive transfinite induction up to $\epsilon_0$ can get us?  E.g., can it get us that PA is $\Pi_3$-sound? $\Pi_4$-sound?

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable with ordinal analysis should answer that, however I suspect that $\Pi_2$ is all you get. Primitive recursive TI up to $\epsilon_0$ certainly does not imply the $\Pi_4$-soundness of PA, as it is itself a $\Pi_3$-axiomatized schema.

Comment: Thanks again!  One more thing: is it *known* that, for some $k$, there's no computable ordinal $\alpha$ (even a much larger ordinal than $\epsilon_0$) such that primitive recursive transfinite induction up to $\alpha$ implies that PA is $\Pi_k$-sound?

Comment: The argument in my last comment actually applies to any computable ordinal $\alpha$. Primitive recursive TI up to $\alpha$ is still $\Pi_3$-axiomatized, and no set of true $\Pi_3$ sentences can imply the $\Sigma_3$-soundness of PA (or even of pure predicate calculus in the language of PA) due to Gödel’s theorem.

Comment: Thanks!  This actually gives me a different view of Gentzen's theorem: I suppose one could say that "really" what it does, is to use the hypothesis of induction up to $\epsilon_0$ to "strengthen your faith in Peano Arithmetic by two quantifiers."  I.e., if you're already satisfied that induction on $\Pi_k$-sentences yields only true conclusions, then Gentzen + $\epsilon_0$ can make you satisfied that induction on $\Pi_{k+2}$-sentences (or whatever) yields only true conclusions.  (Of course, it also gives you that induction on *any* sentences yields only *consistent* conclusions.)

Comment: No, that’s a wrong view. We are talking about the truth of bounded complexity conclusions of *full* induction. Induction on $\Pi_{k+2}$ formulas has a much smaller ordinal than $\epsilon_0$, and its soundness is provable in PA itself.

Comment: Also, $\Pi_k$ transfinite induction up to $\epsilon_0$ cannot be in any useful way decomposed as plain $\Pi_k$ induction “+ $\epsilon_0$”.